# Java class instance values

Tags: java, class, instance

I have a class with a static variable x and a method to set a value.

```
public class mainclass
{
 
    public static int x;
 

    public static int newvalue( int y )
    {
        
    x = y;  
     return y;

    
    }
    
}
```

I have another class to store integer value

```
public class instance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        mainclass main = new mainclass();
        mainclass main1 = new mainclass();
        main.newvalue( 1 );
        System.out.println("x = " + main.x);
        int y = main.x;
        main1.newvalue( 2 );
        System.out.println("x = " + main1.x);
        
        System.out.println("x = " + main.x);
        
    }

}
```

It gives output

```
main: x = 1
main1: x = 2
main: x = 2
```

Now what I like to have an output

```
main: x = 1
main1: x = 2
main: x = 1
```

Is it possible. Please.

Comment: Yes, simply remove the static modifier on the Variable and method

Comment: Although it is possible, you shouldn't call static methods or fields on an instance. This causes exactly the confusion you have right now. `static` means it belongs to the class, not to a specific instance.

Comment: Related: [Why is it possible for objects to change the value of class variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050441/why-is-it-possible-for-objects-to-change-the-value-of-class-variables)

Comment: BTW take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character.

Answer (score 2):

you need to modify the maincalss class as shown below:

```
public class mainclass {

    public int x;

    public int newvalue( int y ) {
    
    x = y;  
     return y;
 
    }

}
```